# Jasmine Async test generation

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jestjs

let's imagine we have a promise that does a large amounts of operations and return helper functions.
A banal example:

```js
const testPromise = testFn => () => {
    const helper = Promise.resolve({testHelper: () => 'an helper function'}) // I/O Promise that returns an helper for testing
    return helper.then(testFn).finally(() => console.log('tear down'));
}

// This describe would work as expected
describe('Async test approach', () => {
    it('A test', testPromise(async ({testHelper}) => {
        expect(testHelper()).toBe('an helper function')
    }))
})

// This part doesn't work

describe('Async describe approach', testPromise(async ({testHelper}) => {

    it('Test 1', () => {
        expect(testHelper()).toBe('an helper function')
    })

    it('Test 2', () => {
        expect(testHelper()).not.toBe('A chair')
    })
}))

}
```

What I would like to achieve is something like the second example where I can use async code within describe without re-evaluating `testPromise`.

`describe` doesn't handle async so I am not even able to loop and create dynamic tests properly.

I did read many comments around saying that `describe` should only be a simple way to group tests but... then... how can someone make async generated tests based on I/O result?

Thanks

= ADDITIONAL CONSIDERATION =

Regarding all the comment you guys kindly added, I should have added few additional details...

I am well aware that tests must be defined synchronously :), that is exactly where problems starts. I totally disagree with that and I am trying to find an alternative that avoids before/after and doing it without specifying an external variable. Within Jest issues there was an open one to address that, it seems they did agree on making describe async but they won't do it. The reason is... Jest is using Jasmine implementation of describe and this "fix" should be done in there.

I wanted to avoid `beforeAll` and `afterAll`, as much as I could. My purpose was creating an easy (and neat) way to define integration tests tailored on my needs without letting users to worry about initialize and tear down stuff around. I will continue to use the Example 1 above style, that seems the best solution to me, even if it would be clearly a longer process.

Comment: Why does the question have both tags? Is it Jasmine or Jest that you ask about?

Comment: Jest is using jasmine's describe. So, as far as I know, in this specific example they are both valid. I should have specified without using beforeAll or afterAll, what I wanted was avoiding  all that entropy and external variable declaration. Something that clearly you don't have in the first case proposed. My question was about doing the same in an elegant way without declaring on top a variable initialize it on the beforeAll and tear down it on the afterAll. With before/after all was my very first implementation but it's not neat (my opinion) and it has to be repeted for every describe.

Comment: If your case is Jasmine, I'd suggest to stick to it. Jest has its own specifics, the problem can be approached differently in Jest, there are setup files. This is specific to the runner you use, what is it? Without it, it needs to be specified in every `describe`. You can override `describe` if needed but this depends on what exactly you do in testPromise. If you will add async code to all suites that don't need this, this will slow down test run.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask
I am using Jest. My current approach is defining a global variable (on jest setup phase), like "testPromise" (see above). Everything is internal to my project and lazily initialized and I don't need to require anything from outside. It works very well. I wanted to make it better without adding beforeAll/afterAll noise, avoiding useless redundancy. Even if...  defining an external variable that is created/modified by afterAll/beforeAll is the canonical approach... I find it a very opinable practice, not functional at all. I think it is just a personal preference.

Comment: As for Jest, it's https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array if async code should run for each test file or https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string if it should run once. beforeAll is the canonical approach for Jest and Jasmine, it can be used in both. I re-added jest tag.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Defining Tests](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#defining-tests). The doc says:

> Tests must be defined synchronously for Jest to be able to collect your tests.

This is the principle for defining test cases. Which means the `it` function should be defined synchronously. That's why your second example doesn't work.

Some I/O operations should be done in `beforeAll`, `afterAll`, `beforeEach`, `afterEach` methods to prepare your test doubles and fixtures. The test should be isolated from the external environment as much as possible.

If you must do this, maybe you can write the dynamically obtained `testHelper` function to a static js file, and then test it in a synchronous way

Answer (score 0):

As it was noted, `describe` serves to group tests.

This can be achieved with `beforeAll`. Since `beforeAll` should be called any way, it can be moved to `testPromise`:

```
const prepareHelpers = (testFn) => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    ...
    return helper.then(testFn);
  })
}

describe('Async describe approach', () => {
  let testHelper;

  prepareHelpers(helpers => { testHelper = helpers.testHelper });
  ...
```