# How to correctly achieve such test suite archtecture with Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have checked all the [guides](https://jestjs.io/docs/architecture) and [examples](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples) on the Jest documentation website, but haven't found anything, that could provide an answer for my question.

I am looking for a pattern which allows me to run test cases for many different functions (in my case it's getters) separately, with Jest.

As for now, in my `example.test.ts` file, I have the following:

```js
import { getterOne, getterTwo, getterThree, ... } from getters;

describe('test suite', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    //connect to MongoDB
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    //disconnect from MongoDB
  })

  //request token from DB, to check it
  it('key', async () => {
    const key = await KeysModel.findOne(_id: 'any').lean();
    expect(key).toMatchSnapshot({
      field: expect.any(String),
    });
  });

  /**
   * predefine key and some other things
   * but I can't call key here, because describe doesn't support
   * async/await, as it should be synchronous
   */


  //test separate getterOne with key variable as an argument

  //test separate getterTwo with key variable as an argument

  //test separate getterThree with key variable as an argument
})
```

But as we all know, I couldn't use the already defined key inside the `it` case. So I could define key once more on the top level, **but**:

- Is it *ok* to re-define the key variable for each getter test case? If I have so many getters, I'll have `xN` absolutely useless requests.
- As I understand it, I couldn't use `async/await` inside `describe`, because *returning a Promise from "describe" is not supported. Tests must be defined synchronously*.

So I am not asking, how to write code, but **what is the correct pattern to writing a dependents test cases, in scenarios like this?**

Could someone provide an example? Should I write more `test` inside `describe` or the common practice is a bit different from that?

What Jest methods should be used and in which order?

> *As for now, I am declaring empty variable via `let` keyword, and use them, like that:*

```
describe('test suite', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    //connect to MongoDB
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    //disconnect from MongoDB
  })

  describe('inside', () => {
    let key;

    beforeAll(async () => {
      key = await KeyModel.findOne();
    })
   
    test('getterOne', async () => {
      const res = await getterOne(key);
      expect(res).toMatchSnapshot({
        id: expect.any(Number)
      });
    });

    //other test with keys..
  
  })
})
```

Does it consider as a good practice?

Comment: *it ok to re-define the key variable for each getter test case?* - yes, it's ok, unless you use `concurrent` tests. A variable in `describe` scope is shared between tests. It's considered a good practice. You can move async operation that is common to tests to beforeEach or beforeAll. Or you can have one tests with multiple assertions if a set of tests depends on what you get asynchronously, because tests should be declared synchronously and be know when test run starts

Comment: @EstusFlask, thank you for that comment, it brings me more confidence than I have for now. To be honest, I prefer more, to see it as an answer, especially if you won't be shy to share a few code examples.

Comment: For the case you described, the example would be exactly as you posted in the second snippet, there's nothing to add, you can make it an answer yourself. There may be less straightforward cases because of sync `describe` limitation, the solutions will be different, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323343/jasmine-async-test-generation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019169/jest-shared-async-code-between-test-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now, I am using the same structure, as was proposed. But I also thankful to [Estus Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus-flask) for pointing me in this direction. I don't use mockups, mainly because I test not just `functions`, but also a DB presence and data persistence.

```js
describe('test suite', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    //connect to MongoDB
  })

  afterAll(async () => {
    //disconnect from MongoDB
  })

  /**
   * another describe stage below
   * with its own after and before and describe stages
   */

})
```